# Using imperative form as a Product Feature

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, writing

I am preparing my RGB Keyboard Product's features. Is it okay to use imperative form? and Are the following sentences correct?

- Change the colors from the app on the phone by connecting via Bluetooth.
- Change the colors with the RGB remote controller.
- Color transition feature according to the rhythm of the song.

Comment: Your feature list reads fine as it is, though you should note you are using the infinitive without 'to', rather than the imperative. (Or a noun as per your last feature). Just as a tip, have you Googled your keyboard's user guide/manual/product listing in English? You could copy from that or at least use it for inspiration.